# How to deploy symfony2 application in localhost with apache2

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have gone through many questions related to this in SO, but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I have copied the demo symfony application to `/var/www/html/myproject` folder. I can only access the `localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php` but not `localhost/myproject/web/app.php` . Basically I want to switch from development environment to prodution environment.

I just get a blank page when I access app.php. How do I solve this issue?

Following is my routing.yml file

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

EDIT

Error log (app/logs/prod.log)

```
[2015-04-06 22:54:53] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at /home/fazlan/ppp/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 144 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /\" at /home/fazlan/ppp/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:144, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/fazlan/ppp/myproject/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:35)"} []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through different tutorials and manuals, I finally was able to solve this issue by the following changes.

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation


_acme_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

AppKernel.php (The whole file is not shown here)

```
public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
             new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle(),

        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            //$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

in the above file AcmeDemoBundle is registered. You have to comment out  `//$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();` to prevent the bundle being registered twice in dev and test environments.

After editing those two files go to the project folder and do

```
php app/console --env=prod cache:clear
```

and then in the browser `localhost/myproject/web/app.php` would load the same bundle as in app_dev.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your bundle and configure routes for it. After this prod environment will be work. It is possible that the acme isnt work in prod.

@Cedric: Acme Demo Bundle is only configured on app_dev.php you have to create another bundle first with proper routes, you can see the list of routes for your bundle in app/config/routing.yml or whatever you set as a the extension of your configs.

More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html).

Comment: Do u have any bundles? Looks like u dont have routes. Try to use routes for acmedemobundle.

Comment: yes the default, Acme bundle. The problem is the application works with dev environment(app_dev.php) but not with app.php

Comment: Thats all! You need to create your bundle and configure routes for it. After this prod environment will be work. It is possible that the acme isnt work in prod. Read doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html)

Comment: i'm sorry, what was the solution again?

Comment: Acme Demo Bundle is only configured on app_dev.php you have to create another bundle first with proper routes, you can see the list of routes for your bundle in `app/config/routing.yml` or whatever you set as a the extension of your configs

Comment: Try this localhost/myproject/web/app.php/Hello/world Sorry for my English

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RaeenHashemi, i just now getting 50 rep.

Comment: @maches When you don't have enough reputation to post a comment, don't. The restriction is not for you to post the CM as an answer.